# How to build 'missing' complex functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, hoogle

How should I aprroach situations when I know type of needed function but it is not defined yet? I suspect function I'm looking for is easily composable from others, but I don't know where to start looking.

```
Prelude> :hoogle (b->b->c)->(a->b)->(a->b)->a->a->c
No results found
```

To be more specific, I have `(b->b->c)` function at hand but I need to process (lift maybe?) the arguments first. Can hoogle find functions with arguments in different order than specified?

This is close to what I need, but I want to apply different function to each argument.

```
Prelude Data.Function> :t on
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as your question asked how this function can be composed from other functions, I would like to point out that you can write it as:

```
import Control.Arrow
on2 :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
on2 f g h = curry (uncurry f . (g *** h))
```

However, the straightforward definition suggested by bheklilr is obviously just as concise and much more readable for people who are not used to working with Arrows.

And, yes, as far as I know, Hoogle *does* also search for functions in which the order of argument types you specified is permuted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find it on hoogle, it probably isn't already defined.  Feel free to define your own as

```
on2 :: (b1 -> b2 -> c) -> (a1 -> b1) -> (a2 -> b2) -> a1 -> a2 -> c
on2 f p1 p2 a1 a2 = f (p1 a1) (p2 a2)
```

But this would lead to expressions like

```
on2 zip init tail xs ys
```

Instead of just

```
zip (init xs) (tail ys)
```

So I don't know if it'd really save you much room.

Comment: I've run into cases where I need to pass specialized equality or comparison functions into others, and that's where something like this comes in really handy (I actually used the "on" function....  I've never needed an on2, but I am sure there are cases).  Without an on2, you have to use a lambda, which I find harder to read.